# Whitespace added after path following a command with sudo

Tags: bash, linux-mint

When I try to execute a command as super user that is followed by a path, the auto-complete (tab) will produce a whitespace after the folder:

Example, in my home folder:

```
"sudo cat Doc" <tab>
```

produces

```
"sudo cat Documents "
```

as opposed to

```
"sudo cat Documents/"
```

This is quite annoying. Any ideas what may be wrong? Did I break it or is this simply a bug?
I am running Linux Mint 13 Mate 64.

Comment: can you confirm that "Document" is a folder, instead of a regular file? ls -al

Comment: It works with any folder, and yes "Documents" is present in the working directory and is itself a directory.

Comment: I do some tests, and when I have a broken symbolic link, I get the same situation as you:  
ads -> koaso  
sudo cat ads<tab> generates a space

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[This topic](https://askubuntu.com/questions/41707/bash-auto-completion-with-added-spaces-why-and-how-to-fix) seems to fix it.
I am still unsure why this occurred though. I am quite certain it wasn't an issue until today.

Comment: Problem still persists for pluma/gedit: `"sudo pluma /etc" <tab>` produces `"sudo pluma /etc "` and not `"sudo pluma /etc/"`

Comment: As mentioned in the last comment at [link](http://askubuntu.com/questions/41707/bash-auto-completion-with-added-spaces-why-and-how-to-fix), the Adobe Reader messes with the completion definitions.

Answer (score 1):

You can use bash-completion for the issue. For Debian/Ubuntu

```
sudo apt-get install bash-completion
```

Comment: Apt tells me it is already the newest version.